# Subdomain Backlink

Tags: seo, backlinks

I bought a domain, after building my app I'm using Ahref's to audit my website. I notice that many backlinks are appearing with a good domain authority pointing not to my root domain but to a subdomain.

I'm thinking of creating the subdomain and redirecting it with status code 301 to my root domain.  Is this the best approach or should I make this subdomain as the same of the domain root?  Basically having 2 websites?

Comment: I think this is to opinion based to be meaningfully answered. Also, depending on the back links and their relevance doing this can help, but it can also hurt your SEO.

Comment: What are these links for?  When were they created?  Do the links point to the subdomain's home page or to a deeper URL on the subodmain?  Do you have content that is appropriate to satisfy these links?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details so that this can be re-opened and answered.